# Animating a shape

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am trying to make the shape I created move across the screen. I have a picture I got from Google move across the screen to the right but now I want my circle I created to move. Here is my coding. Am I missing anything, what am I missing. The circle I created is on the screen but doesn't move

```
bif="background.jpg"
mif="volleyball.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,800),0,32)

triangle= [[1000, 500], [950, 500], [975, 450]]
color= (250,145,123)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
ball_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

x=0
y=0
clock=pygame.time.Clock() #We opened our clock method.
speed=250 #We set our speed

color=(176,23,31)
position=(2,412)
radius=(90)

movex = 0
movey = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type== QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(ball_c, (x,160))

    milli=clock.tick()
    seconds=milli/1000. #We converted milliseconds into seconds
    dm=seconds*speed
    x+=dm 

    x+=dm
    y+=dm
    movex+=dm
    movey+=dm

    if x>1280: 
        x=0


    for point in triangle:
        point[0] += movey
        if y == 150:
            point[1]= movex

    screen.lock()
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,color,position,radius)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,color,triangle)

    screen.unlock()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Also, you update `x` but use `position` to draw.

Comment: how would I do that, sorry Im new at this can you put it in my coding. and no thats not my indentation i had to do that to post this question

Comment: You should ensure that the code in your question has the same indentation as you are actually using, otherwise it is very hard to debug. You can copy it directly into the question text box, select it, then use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: I fixed it. can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Every time you `draw` the `circle`:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen,color,position,radius)
```

You put it at `position`. This is set initially:

```
position=(2,412)
```

But then *never changes*, so it is always in the same place. You need to update `position` each time through the loop, e.g.

```
position = (position[0] + dx, position[1] + dy)
```

Where `dx` and `dy` are how far you want the `circle` to move on each axis.

Comment: How do I make it move different directions like up,down,left,right,diagonal

Comment: @user3483040 try varying `dx` and `dy` and see what happens.

Comment: How would I do that can you put it in my code . sorry I'm very new at this and don't really understand

Comment: Just like `x` and `movex`, calculate a `dx` then alter `position` as I show. Experiment!